# How can i center the panning of the camera perspective view ,respectively to the viewport?(SOLVED)

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, camera

(SOLVED)
Solution: Press home key when in camera view.

=========================================================

im in camera perspective, (numpad 0 view) is there a way to center the camerawindow to the center of the viewport?

[image]

and maybe try even to fit it? i saw the command Zoom camera 1:1 but it still wont center it. i would like the camera to be centered. I know theres a ctrl+numppad  4 , 6 ,8 ,2 but the step is too big for what i need. i would need to make it precisely in the same position everytime i go back to this view or at least have a button or script that puts it in the same position always. (must be as precise as possible, thats why i cannot do it by hand with shift + middle mouse and zoom)

if found that the command view3d.view_pan is the one the ctrl+numpad 4682 , use to move the view, but i still dont know how to use this in python script if i do this through a script.

Answer (score 2):

Try **View** > **Cameras** > **Frame Camera Bounds**

You can also press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key.

Comment: @RubenD'Andrea See my new edit.